# `NullPointerException` when trying to run no-op `LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase` on IntelliJ Community built from source

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've tried to create a simple IDEA plugin and a test case for it based on [this](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/writing_tests_for_plugins/tests_prerequisites.html) manual:

```
package com.example;

import com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase;

public class NoopTest extends LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase {
    public void testNothing() {

    }
}
```

Then I create JUnit run configuration, make it run this class, point working directory to `D:\idea-community\bin` directory (see below) and set VM options as per the manual:

```
-ea -Xbootclasspath/p:../out/classes/production/boot -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=320m -Didea.system.path=../test-system -Didea.home.path=../ -Didea.config.path=../test-config -Didea.test.group=ALL_EXCLUDE_DEFINED
```

Then I run the test in debug mode and get the following error:

```
CompositeException (2 nested):
------------------------------
[0]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.testFramework.IdeaTestUtil.createMockJdk(IdeaTestUtil.java:77)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.IdeaTestUtil.getMockJdk(IdeaTestUtil.java:72)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.IdeaTestUtil.getMockJdk17(IdeaTestUtil.java:85)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase$1.getSdk(LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase.java:60)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.LightProjectDescriptor.lambda$createContentEntry$3(LightProjectDescriptor.java:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootModificationUtil.updateModel(ModuleRootModificationUtil.java:143)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.LightProjectDescriptor.createContentEntry(LightProjectDescriptor.java:134)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.LightProjectDescriptor.lambda$setUpProject$0(LightProjectDescriptor.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.run(WriteAction.java:105)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.LightProjectDescriptor.setUpProject(LightProjectDescriptor.java:52)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.LightPlatformTestCase.initProject(LightPlatformTestCase.java:242)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.LightPlatformTestCase.doSetup(LightPlatformTestCase.java:303)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.LightIdeaTestFixtureImpl.setUp(LightIdeaTestFixtureImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.lambda$setUp$24(CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.java:1190)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:14)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtilKt.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.setUp(CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.java:1189)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase.setUp(LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase.java:76)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.defaultRunBare(UsefulTestCase.java:358)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:14)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtilKt$runInEdtAndWait$2.run(EdtTestUtil.kt:59)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch$$$capture(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

[1]: java.lang.AssertionError: setUp() has not been called
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.BaseFixture.tearDown(BaseFixture.java:48)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.LightTempDirTestFixtureImpl.tearDown(LightTempDirTestFixtureImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.lambda$null$32(CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.java:1241)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:14)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtilKt.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt:37)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.lambda$tearDown$33(CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.java:1241)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.RunAll.collectExceptions(RunAll.java:60)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.RunAll.run(RunAll.java:52)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.impl.CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.tearDown(CodeInsightTestFixtureImpl.java:1247)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase.tearDown(LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase.java:88)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.defaultRunBare(UsefulTestCase.java:370)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:14)
    at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtilKt$runInEdtAndWait$2.run(EdtTestUtil.kt:59)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch$$$capture(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

My set-up:

1. IDEA Community, built locally by clicking "Build - Build project" after following the "[Check Out And Build Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/checkout_and_build_community.html)" manual. Path to the source root is something like `D:\idea-community\`, so that there is `D:\idea-community\getPlugins.bat`. Git commit is `ef98a0ccb`.
2. IDEA successfully runs in debug mode.
3. This IDEA is added as an IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK to my plugin project.
4. I successfully run IDEA from my plugin project, and even navigate the source code.

How do I fix the error when running the test and make it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by removing `D:\idea-community\out\production\intellij.pycharm.community\META-INF\PyCharmCorePlugin.xml`, but that feels like a cheat because that file gets recreated with every build.

After further investigation I found out that `PlatformTestCase.doAutodetectPlatformPrefix()` detects `PyCharmCore` instead of `Idea` and it looks like mock Java SDK (or whatever) is not loaded in that case, hence `NullPointerException`.

I've found some mentions of similar problems on JetBrains forums [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206784065-Problem-using-test-fixtures-CORE-PLUGIN-ID-not-registered-with-IC) (from 2009), [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206766155-Test-example-not-working) (from 2012) and [there](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206115979-Intellij-sample-test-ERROR-Invalid-home-path) (from 2014). It looks like platform autodetection in tests [is a recent thing](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/6061bb407f2596038628222018317847585f2662) (from 2015). Moreover, it looks like it overrides any `-Didea.platform.prefix=Idea` that I pass as JVM options, so I don't see any better solution.